# Getting wrong number of digits with my random phone number generator

Tags: ruby

I am using the following to generate 10 random digits:

```
10.times.map {|i| (0...9).to_a[rand(10)] }.join
```

But if you run this, you will notice it does not give you 10 random digits. I do not understand why. The **times** iterator will run 10 times:

```
10.times
```

For each time we invoke the iterator, we also chain the **map** call to it and pass a black. This ensures that the contents of the block will be called 10 times too:

```
10.times.map {|i| }
```

Inside the block, we take an interval, a set of values with a beginning and an end. In Ruby, we can do this with **range**. We take a range of digits from 0-9.

```
(0...9)
```

We call **to_a** on the range which will take all elements in range and stick them as indexes in an array. to_a has a class method **[]**. This returns a new array for each item in the original array based on the given value passed in.

```
to_a[]
```

When max is an Integer, **rand** returns a random integer greater than or equal to zero and less than max. We use rand to generate our new values.

```
rand
```

Since 10.times is invoked 10 times we should have 10 random digits between 0 and 9, inclusive. We just use join to combine them at the end:

```
join
```

Yet I run this and it does not give me 10 numbers:

```
10.times.map {|i| (0...9).to_a[rand(10)] }.join
 => "151063260"
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: On a side note, I am also using insert to add the hyphens: str.insert(3,"-")

Comment: The key here is ... is not inclusive, but .. is inclusive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whenever you do `(0...9).to_a[rand(10)]` you're in the probabilty that `rand(10)` returns 9, and in a range `0...9` there's no 9, that's why you get some nil values, which are finally "removed" from the string that `join` generates.

An example could be:

```
p 10.times.map {|i| (0...9).to_a[rand(10)] }
# [6, 6, 7, 1, 1, 1, nil, 1, nil, 7]
```

You have two nil values there, which then "disappear", because the result of applying `to_s` in a nil object is an empty string `""`:

```
p [6, 6, 7, 1, 1, 1, nil, 1, nil, 7].join
"66711117"
```

The easiest fix would be change the rand argument to 10, being 9 the max value it can return, and the max value in the range (0..9):

```
10.times.map { (0..9).to_a[rand(10)] }.join # Omitted the block variable
```

Although notice you could get the same approach using sample:

```
10.times.map { (0..9).to_a.sample }
```

Or even better Array.new with a block:

```
Array.new(10) { rand(10) }
```

At least the tree implementations differ in a visible amount of time, so you can choose (of course there are more):

```
rand       1.340000   0.020000   1.360000 (  1.368701) # 10.times.map { (0..9).to_a[rand(10)] }
sample     1.170000   0.020000   1.190000 (  1.194385) # 10.times.map { (0..9).to_a.sample }
Array.new  0.250000   0.000000   0.250000 (  0.253762) # Array.new(10) { rand(10) }
```

*(using benchmark over 100000 iterations)*

Comment: `(0...10).to_a.shuffle` will always generate unique numbers.
And either `(0...9).to_a.sample` or `rand(9)` will miss number `9`.

Comment: Sure. Edited. Thanks.

Comment: Side note:  just using `rand` would be the fastest e.g. `rand(1_000_000_000..9_999_999_999).to_s` since building the `Array` seems like an intermediary step to generating the string.

Answer (score 2):

According to the [docs](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Range.html):

> Ranges constructed using .. run from the beginning to the end inclusively. Those created using ... exclude the end value..

So `a..b` is like `a <= x <= b`, whereas `a...b` is like `a <= x < b`, ie:

```
(0...9).to_a # => [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
```

And `rand(10)` will return from `0` to `9`. If it returns `9`, the command inside the block will return `nil`

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8][9] # => nil

[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, nil].join # => '012345678'
```

---

In order to solve your problem, you can use `(0..9).to_a.sample` or `rand(10)` inside your block, or even the better solution:

```
Array.new(10) { rand(10) }
```

Comment: Or `rand(0..9)`.

Comment: @SebastianPalma, Thank you. I forgot to convert it to array before calling `sample`. Lemme update the answer.